# How should I identify the inline javascript that is the dependent of a wp_enqueue_script?

Tags: javascript, array, wp-enqueue-style

I want to run my own JavaScript on a specific WordPress page but only after a third party's plugin runs as I am trying to slightly modify that plugin.  My problem is that my JavaScript is running before, not after, the plugin's script.  Is my mistake in how I am referring to the plugin's script (i.e. the dependent script) in the $deps array?

```
<?php  
// What was originally in the child theme’s function.php file  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'you_enqueue_styles' );

function you_enqueue_styles() 
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}

// Added by me to the child theme’s function.php file
function load_new_js() {
    if( is_page( 692 ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('modify_plugin_js', 'https://www.example.com/mycustomscript.js', array('greetingnow', 'jquery'), '',false);
    }
}
// Should I even bother putting in a priority of 100 to try and force this to be run last?
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_new_js', 100);
```

This is what the script in the HTML looks like:

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
<!-- This is the dependent code that should run first and is put directly into the HTML file by the third party Plugin provider -->
var greetingnow = "Good Morning!";
alert(greetingnow);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's okay to add dependent script in your wp_enqueue_script function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AntonLukin, I know it is okay but my problem is the dependencies are not working as I expected.

Comment: I want greetingnow to run first and then mycustomscript.js.

Comment: Where is greetingnow enqueued? If in another plugin, how is the plugin enqueing the script?

Comment: greetingnow is not enqueued anywhere.  I thought I did not have to enqueue it since it is already a script in the HTML page.  Do I still have to include it in the enqueue function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this...

```
function load_new_js() {
    if( is_page( 692 ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'modify_plugin_js',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/mycustomscript.js',
            array('jquery','greetingnow')
        );

    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, what plugin are you using?

Comment: I tried that as well, to no avail.  The plugin is Caldera Form's add on for Google Places autocomplete address search.

Comment: down vote?  really?  Just trying to help by narrowing it down

Comment: I also discovered that I needed to request a new (replacement) Google API code; secondly I did not have a callback in the API URL key.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`wp_add_inline_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/). It lets you add and inline script that's dependent on an enqueued script:

```
function wpse_320377_register_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'my-script-handle', 'https://www.example.com/mycustomscript.js', [ 'jquery' ], '', true );
    wp_add_inline_script( 'my-script-handle', 'var greetingnow = "Good Morning!"; alert(greetingnow);', 'before' );

    if ( is_page( 692 ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script-handle' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_320377_register_scripts' );
```

In that example, it registers a custom script, `my-script-handle`, and then attaches the inline script to it using `wp_add_inline_script()` so that whenever `my-script-handle` is enqueued, the inline script will be output right before it. The result will look something like this:

```
<script>
    var greetingnow = "Good Morning!"; alert(greetingnow);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.example.com/mycustomscript.js"></script>
```

Comment: wp_add_inline_script() is a good suggestion. But the output is the other way around: I want the inline script to be executed first and then mycustomscript.js.

Comment: You can set the third argument of `wp_add_inline_script()` to `'before'` to put the inline script first. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That would work for me except that the inline text is populated by a third party's plugin, the end result being it would be outputted to the HTML twice.  I just want my .js file executed after the inline script runs.